# Proving an invariant relationship

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum, inertial-frames, invariants

Two particles, moving at relativistic speeds in the x direction, are observed to have energies E<sub>1</sub> and E<sub>2</sub>, and momenta p<sub>1</sub> and p<sub>2</sub> in frame A. Frame B moves at relativistic speed v relative to frame A, also in the x direction. The particle energies and momenta in frame B are E<sub>1</sub>′ , E<sub>2</sub>′ , p′<sub>1</sub> and p′<sub>2</sub>.

How do I proof the following relationship?

[image]

Comment: You need some extra conditions here. How are the 4-vectors on each side related?

Comment: @probably_someone I've added some more information to the question

Comment: So does i run from 1 to 2 here?

Comment: @probably_someone yup, i run from 1 to 2 here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that Lorentz transformations preserve the length of the 4-momentum vector for each particle. In Minkowski space, this length is $E^2-p^2c^2$ up to sign convention, which is irrelevant here. Since this quantity is frame-independent (frame changes are Lorentz transformations) for each particle, the sum must also be frame-independent.